# Android ListView extended databind

Tags: android

I am created android `ListView` and bind data from SQLite database.
**The issue is when filling the data into ListView how to set primary keys with List view items in order to go forward with that selected item.**

[image: List View Filled with data from SQLite]

**When click the List View item Get the dialog bow below with ItemKey and Item Name.**
Get item key from list view and querying database and get details according to that key.

[image]

**Task**: I don't want to show Item Key on List view,But when I clicked on `ListView` item,it should get the item key from that clicked position and send it to next Activity.

(On C# we can create custom properties for text-box but i don't know dot it same for the android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your primary key is an ID, then in the list adapter, override `getItemId` and return the ID from this function. An example can be found at http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

```
private class StableArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

  HashMap<String, Integer> mIdMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

  public StableArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<String> objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i) {
      mIdMap.put(objects.get(i), i);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public long getItemId(int position) {
    String item = getItem(position);
    return mIdMap.get(item);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
  }

}
```